# Как назначить на кнопку действие добавления задачи вместо клика на Menu item?

Tags: android, android-studio

Написал приложение "список задач" по туториалу. Задачи добавляются при клике на пункт меню(иконка плюса справа вверху)

Как сделать,чтобы новая задача добавлялась не по клику на пункт меню, а на мою кастомную кнопку?
Разметку кнопки я сделал, а вот как повесить метод,который бы всё это реализовывал?

Main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_task"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_item"
    android:title="@string/add_task"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

item_todo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/hi"
    android:textSize="20sp" />




    <Button
    android:id="@+id/task_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="deleteTask"
    android:text="@string/done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_todo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

<Button

android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
android:layout_width="65dp"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/circle"
/>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

класс MainActivity:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TaskHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
Button btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHelper = new TaskHelper(this);
    mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    updateUI();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("New Task")
                    .setMessage("Add a new task")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new ` 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {`
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ` 
     which) {`
                        String task = 
     String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE, 
   null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            updateUI();

                        }
                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

       }
    }


   private void updateUI() {

    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[] {Task.TaskEntry._ID, 
    Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo, 
 R.id.task_title, taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

public void deleteTask(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Task.TaskEntry.TABLE, Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?", 
new String[]{task});
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}


}
```

класс Task:

```
package com.kentforth.list5;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Task {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "ToDoDB";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE = "tasks";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
      }

   }
```

класс TaskHelper:

```
package com.kentforth.list5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public TaskHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Task.DB_NAME, null, Task.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + Task.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                                   Task.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY 
KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                   Task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT 
NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + Task.TaskEntry.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны присвоить кнопке OnClickListener:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   mHelper = new TaskHelper(this);
   mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
   btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addTask();
        }
   });
   updateUI();
}
```

Код добавления новой заметки вынесите в отдельную функцию для удобства:

```
private void addTask(){
final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)...
   // и так далее
 .create();
 dialog.show();
}
```

Подробнее о onClickListener [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/16-urok-9-obrabotchiki-sobytij-na-primere-button.html) и [здесь](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928).

Comment: Благодарю! то,что нужно)